# unordered_map pointer to element's value valid after resize?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, unordered-map

If I have an `unordered_map<key, someNiceObject>`

(note `someNiceObject` is not a pointer)

I have an API which inserts a new element, then returns a pointer to `someNiceObject` now in the map.

If I perform further insertions into the map, there could be a capacity change. If that happens is the pointer still valid or not?

I tried reading
[Basic questions: Pointers to objects in unordered_maps (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652901/basic-questions-pointers-to-objects-in-unordered-maps-c), 
[std::unordered_map pointers/reference invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868640/stdunordered-map-pointers-reference-invalidation) and
http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#9

and couldn't locate the necessary information

Thanks all

edit: it seems that the pointer would be valid (https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/do-insert-erase-invalidate-pointers-to-elements-values-of-std-unordered_map.961062/)

though would appreciate a second confirmation from someone here on SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert):

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. **References are not invalidated.**

Which implies that pointers aren't invalidated either. This is possible because `std::unordered_map` is conceptually can be thought of as `std::vector<std::forward_list<std::pair<Key, Value>>>`. And since  `std::forward_list`, like any other linked list, allocates each element separately, changes to the list don't affect the memory location of it's elements.

Comment: @Prof, I've extended my explanation.

Comment: so for completeness, both the key and value are safe to take a reference to

Comment: @r3musn0x The link you include now says the following: "If rehashing occurs (due to the insertion), all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise (no rehashing), iterators and references are not invalidated. If the insertion is successful, pointers and references to the element obtained while it is held in the node handle are invalidated, and pointers and references obtained to that element before it was extracted become valid. (since C++17)". Thus, it seems like pointer stability is not provided?

Answer (score 11):

`std::unordered map` is unusual in that the iterator invalidation rules do NOT apply to references to elements (excluding removal but what can you do when the item is gone?). A capacity change is not important. The problem is when the `unordered map` rehashes. Rehashing will invalidate all iterators, but will not invalidate references.

From point 9 of **[unord.req]** in the C++ Standard (citing n4618 because that's what I have on hand at the moment),

> The elements of an unordered associative container are organized into *buckets*. Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket. The number of buckets is automatically increased as elements are added to an unordered associative container, so that the average number of elements per bucket is kept below a bound. Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, **but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements.** For `unordered_multiset` and `unordered_multimap`, rehashing preserves the relative ordering of equivalent elements.

**emphasis mine**